# Write line by line to file using java.nio

Tags: java

I want to make .txt file with names of files in dir. I can't use java.io, only java.nio so i have problem with write string line by line. In .txt i have only last string saved. Please help

```
        Path file = (new File(path+"\\").toPath());
    //    Stream<Path> directoryListing = Files.list(file);
        Path filesList = Paths.get(path+"/listoffiles.txt");
        Files.walk(Paths.get(path)).forEach(filein->{
        String name=filein.getFileName().toString();
            try {
                Files.writeString(filesList,name);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the writeString docs? (Noting that "writing line by line" is orthogonal to writing a list of file names to a file.)

Comment: You can't use `File` if you are not allowed to use `java.io`

Answer (score 3):

Specify the `StandardOpenOption.APPEND` `OpenOption` as the last argument to `Files.writeString`. When this option is specified, data will be written from the end of the file rather than the beginning. Make sure each string that is written also ends with a newline(`\n`), to separate the lines.

Comment: @BloodyFerret If this answer solved your problem, consider marking it as the accepted answer!